# Why does svn:executable work for one script and not the other?

Tags: linux, svn, system-properties

I have a bash script (.sh file) and a Python script (.py) file in the same directory. Both have the svn:executable permission. However when I do an 'svn update', only the Bash script gets executable permission set.

Any ideas why? (If I manually set the permission on the Python script it runs fine.)

DOH! Turns out I had a typo. It had the property 'sv:executable' (missing n). discovered with loentar's propget/propset.

Comment: As others have said: cannot reproduce it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is command:

```
svn propget svn:executable script.py
```

outputs "*" ?

if not, use this:

```
svn propset svn:executable '*' script.py
```

Answer (score 3):

are you sure it's set?  I ran a quick test in my svn sandbox and python scripts work just fine.

```
user@host sandbox> svn proplist script.py
Properties on 'script.py':
  svn:executable
user@host sandbox> ll script.py
-rwxr-x---  user user apiWriter.py
user@host sandbox>
```